# RN-52 Bluetooth module

Tags: bluetooth

I was wondering what module instead of RN-52 can I use for my project which requires a Bluetooth module supporting the AVRCP profile?

It seems this product is retired and I don't know what alternative module I can choose.

I would appreciate it if you could help with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options for this. There are many Bluetooth modules out there and you can even use an HCI dongle on a Linux machine with BlueZ (the Linux Bluetooth stack). Have a look at the links below:-

- [Any alternative to RN-52](https://www.reddit.com/r/arduino/comments/6wijek/any_alternatives_to_rn52/)
- Microchip's [BM62](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/bm62) and [BM64](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/BM64)
- [Laird's BTM51x series](https://www.lairdconnect.com/support/faqs/btm51x-series-btm51x-simultaneous-profiles)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you know how I can use HID profile to control a media player remotely. For example, using remote buttons to increase, decrease or skip and other functions related to media player with HID profile. I am aiming to buy Flora Bluefruit  LE for my project and use its HID profile to control my phone's music player remotely.

Comment: I suggest that you post a separate question about this unless you think this is related to the above? The reason why I think it is not related is because Flora Bluefruit LE is a Bluetooth Low Energy board (BLE) while your question above is for a classic Bluetooth profile (AVRCP).